# Xamarin form/ios: When app in foreground using timer to periodically download datas and app inactive using fetch

Tags: ios, xamarin, timer, background, xamarin.ios

I am working on Xamarin form with iOS. I am having difficult on making the right decision to what route to go for when dealing with periodically update/downloading data from server.

I am thinking of using a timer running and periodically download new content from the server when app in foreground. When application was running the only solution is to use Background Fetch. After back to foreground, the timer continue to run.

Only problem is the application is in background, which user click on home button. I can see the timer get stopped at some point in minutes.

I can't tell whether the background fetch is started to run or not.

Comment: Run/Debug the app in the iOS simulator using the `Background Fetch` configuration to force a fetch to happen.

Comment: Having a timer running at the foreground to download data periodically and using fetch to download data in background. Is this right way to go.

Comment: Sure, You can use the .Net framework Timer and spin up a `Task` on the Task-based thread pool if you want, I tend to use the iOS framework features over the .Net ones. When in the foreground I use `NSTimer` with a background task (`UIApplication.SharedApplication.BeginBackgroundTask`) and `BackgroundTimeRemaining` to determine if I should allow the task to continue or if I should clean things up if the OS is entering background mode (the iOS framework is background aware, the .Net framework is not) and then let the OS schedule my background fetch code

Comment: Thanks.. Last question is the background task and background fetch will ever run at the same time during the background execution of the background task even though the background task have a limited time for execution.

Comment: Sure, a background task and fetch *could* be running at the same time, if entering into background you fire up a background task to complete something (i.e. committing a transaction to insure that your DB is up to date, stopping a file update to avoid file corruption, etc... ), the OS could fire up a fetch (not that I've every seen that happen upon entering background mode), but the code in that fetch is yours, so you can read a flag and exit the fetch if needed...

Comment: You are right, thanks you.